# Sample and hold using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this

|  | ID | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | NaN |
| 3 | 3 | 20 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 1 | 30 | NaN |
| 5 | 2 | 30 | NaN |
| 6 | 4 | 30 | NaN |

I want to do sample and hold for each ID, using the last known non-null value to impute some of the nulls based on the parameter `max_time`. For every row where `Value` is null and time is `t`, if there is a row with the same `ID` with time `t_other` such than `t-max_time <= t_other <= t`, then I want to replace the `Value` of my row with the `Value` of the row with the max `t_other` that satisfies this constraint.

For example, in the table shown above, if `max_time=10`, then for `ID = 1` at `Time = 20` we have a null `Value` which can be filled by the value at `Time = 10`. So the result would become

|  | ID | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 10 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 | 1.0 |
| 3 | 3 | 20 | 4.0 |
| 4 | 1 | 30 | NaN |
| 5 | 2 | 30 | NaN |
| 6 | 4 | 30 | NaN |

The other nulls don't have a value in the last 10 time units to be able to fill them so they stay nulls.

I asked ChatGPT and it gave the solution

```py
def fill_nulls(group):
    # Fill nulls with the last non-null value
    group['Value'] = group['Value'].ffill()
    
    # Calculate the time difference between consecutive rows
    time_diff = group['Time'].diff()
    
    # Set nulls to NaN if the time difference is greater than 10
    group['Value'][time_diff > 10] = np.nan

    return group

filled_df = df.groupby('ID').apply(fill_nulls)
```

But this is using the fact that row index 2 is filled to mean that row index 4 should not be replaced with null, and filling `1.0` there as well, which is not what I want.

I think the best we would be to fill all rows and replace the ones that should not have been filled back with null, like what ChatGPT tried, but I can't figure out how to write the logic of which rows should be replaced back with nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean mask and `merge`:

```
max_time = 10

m = df['Value'].isna()
vals = (df[m].reset_index().merge(df[~m], on='ID')
             .query('Time_x - Time_y <= @max_time')
             .drop_duplicates('index', keep='last')
             .set_index('index')['Value_y'])
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(vals)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID  Time  Value
0   1    10    1.0
1   2    10    2.0
2   1    11    1.1  # <- ADDED
3   1    20    1.1  # <- FILLED
4   3    20    4.0
5   1    30    NaN
6   2    30    NaN
7   4    30    NaN
```

Comment: It does not work if there are multiple entries in the table that can potentially fill a missing value. E.g. if there was a row (1, 11, 1.1), then this row and the row (1, 10, 1.0) can both fill ID=1 at Time=20, so we get the error 

`ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels`

Comment: @k-c. I updated my answer related to your comment. Can you check it please?

Comment: Looks like it works as intended now